IntelliJ IDEA "Commit Changes" changed, how can I restore it to its original form
now
before
How can I restore it to before
I have read those two questions:
The "Local Changes" tab does not show up in the IntelliJ IDEA Git tool window
Can't find Git local changes in Intellij Idea 2020.1
but those are not what I want.

You have to resize it, it seems diff view is taking your whole space:
Place the cursor on diff line and resize.
